# ARG_MAX modifications reasoning

Tags: linux-kernel

recently I've learned that one can change the default value of `ARG_MAX` for the machine (after recompiling the kernel etc).

I'm curious about why should one do so? what is a possible reason or need that will require such modification?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you have the code, you can modify anything.  Being able to make any change doesn't imply that you _should_ make every change.

Comment: This I understand :) question is - when is such thing needed?

Comment: Generally, never?